# Dynamical URL in $httpbackend - Angular unit testing

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, url, dynamic, httpbackend

I am trying to dynamically add URL parameter to `$httpbackend.whenGET`

```
urlAll = "http://localhost:8080/api/Log";
urlById = "http://localhost:8080/api/Log?id=";
```

- `$httpBackend.whenGET(urlAll).respond(...);` - This is Working fine
- `$httpBackend.whenGET(urlById).respond(...);` - Not working

I append id dynamically to `urlById` when I call mock service.  Since it is a dynamic value and the url is changing with dynamic id value, url is not matching with `urlById` (which is passed to `httpbackend`).  Hence, throwing below exception.

> Unexpected request: `GET /http:\/\/localhost:8080\/api\/Log?id=/1e970422-a1a7-4ea5-9f74-1c84b53d7bc4`
>   No more request expected

Gone through different posts and tried with regex.  but ended up with below exception:

> Unexpected request: `GET /http:\/\/localhost:8080\/api\/Log\?id=.*/14f99a26-7850-4aa6-9953-db73fb1a1cab`
>   Expected GET `/http:\/\/localhost:8080\/api\/Log\?id=.*/.*/g`

Any idea on how to add dynamical url to `$httpbackend`?

Most of the posts say the theoretical solutions and some posts given code changes, which didn't work.  Any idea on what is wrong above?

Comment: i have the same problem with no slution

Comment: i get it forward, that thing named regex is too tin line - u got's to be extremely careful what are you typing - it is a g.d. hard syntax